# Intellij Idea debug dependency jar file specified in Maven

Tags: debugging, maven-2, intellij-idea

I want to  debug a project in Intellij Idea. The project dependency is managed by Maven and I have attached the source code for all the maven dependencies and have also added the actual dependency projects as modules. But the debugger does not work when I have breakpoints in one of the dependency project.

Am I missing something? I have tried to refresh my cache after adding my source lookup to the dependency jar files in module setting.

Intellij Idea version 11 and Maven version 2.2.

Comment: It would help if you could provide a sample project to reproduce this problem. Note that manual module configuration will be discarded on Maven reimport, all the dependencies must be defined via `pom.xml`.

Comment: The project is pretty big. I will try to create a sample project and test it and upload that project if it fails again.